# Angular2 install issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Anyone know what the issue with the latest installation of angular-cli. It was working fine before but now giving me error such as "The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed."

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded your typescript using npm.

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

If problem still persist make sure sure you're using the latest version of NodeJS, npm.

You can also try updating cli.

```
[sudo] npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli 

npm cache clean 

[sudo] npm install -g @angular/cli
```